# How can I get the condition of positive semi-definite of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{pmatrix} 
2a & \frac{xy}{|x||y|} \\
\frac{xy}{|x||y|} & 2a 
\end{pmatrix}$

I tried using the definition of positive semidefinite and I think I got some confusion finally. Is it $a \geq 1/2$, that's my answer, but I think that just depend on the sign of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume $x, y = \pm 1$. We calculate the characteristic polynomial to be 
$(2a - \lambda)^2 - (xy)^2 = \lambda^2 - 4 a \lambda + 4 a^2 - 1 = (\lambda - 2a + 1) (\lambda - 2 a - 1).$ Thus we need $2a - 1, 2a + 1 \geq 0$. This happens if and only if
$2a \geq 1$ so $ a \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Note $(xy)^2 = 1$ regardless of the sign, so the sign doesnt effect the calculation.